# JMeter, postprocessing a sample

Tags: java, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

in my project i would want to implement a plugin for JMeter.

So currently I am stuck at sampler - postprocessing step.

```
@Override
public void postProcessSampler(HTTPSamplerBase sampler, SampleResult result) 
{
    super.postProcessSampler(sampler, result);
    String postData = sampler.getPropertyAsString(HTTPSamplerBase.ARGUMENTS);

    // ...
    // apply some operations to postData
    // ...
    // 
    // try to write it back to sampler : approach1
    //      sampler.removeProperty(HTTPSamplerBase.ARGUMENTS);
    //      sampler.addNonEncodedArgument(HTTPSamplerBase.ARGUMENTS, postData, "");
    // Fails
}
```

So at the postprocessing step i would like to change the request body, whcih is usually stored in `HTTPSamplerBase.ARGUMENTS` property. However, somehow i cannot set anything to this field. Redefining it with another string gives me a class cast error. If I try operating with strings, then i get invocation exception...

So my question is, what is the correct way to change the sampler's post body?

Regards and thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out [HTTPSamplerBase.getArguments() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerBase.html#getArguments--) instead, example code:

```
sampler.getArguments().removeAllArguments();
sampler.addNonEncodedArgument("foo","bar","");
sampler.setPostBodyRaw(true);
```

Also be aware that for this form of post-processing you don't even need to come up with a plugin, all can be done via [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) language. The above code should work just fine

Comment: Hey, thank your for your response. Yes, I am aware that such a feature exists, but the thing is, i want to do an automated xpath generation and further implantation of xpath extracted variables into the post requests of the further collected samples